# Как сделать фильтр по минимальной и максимальной цене?

Tags: wordpress, acf, wp-query

на просторах интернета нашел код для создания фильтра, не могу понять куда именно я должен вставить свою цену которая задается через ACF the_field('cost-house');

html

```
    <input type="text" name="price_min" placeholder="от" />
    <input type="text" name="price_max" placeholder="до" />
```

functions.php

```
    function new_filter_function(){
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date'
    );
 
    // categories
    if( isset( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) )
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
            )
        );
    
    //  Минимальная - максимальная цена
    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] || isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
        $args['meta_query'] = array( 'relation'=>'AND' );
 
    if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] && isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] ) {
        $args['meta_query'][] = array(
            'key' => _price,
            'value' => array( $_POST['price_min'], $_POST['price_max'] ),
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'between'
        );
    } else {

        if( isset( $_POST['price_min'] ) && $_POST['price_min'] )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => _price,
                'value' => $_POST['price_min'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '>'
            );
 
        if( isset( $_POST['price_max'] ) && $_POST['price_max'] )
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key' => _price,
                'value' => $_POST['price_max'],
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => '<'
            );
    }
 
    $args['post_type'] = 'houses';

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
 
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div class="slider__item">
                <div class="slider__img">
                    <a class="slider__link" href="#"></a>
                    <img src="img/slider1.png" alt="дом">
                </div>
                <div class="slider__info">
                    <div class="info-name">
                        <span class="info-micro">новые сады</span>
                        <div class="info-discription">
                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info-icons">
                            <div class="info-icons-item beds">
                                <img src="img/bed.png" alt="спальни">
                                <span>2</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="info-icons-item bathrooms">
                                <img src="img/shower.png" alt="ванные">
                                <span>2</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-price">
                        <div class="area">
                            45<span class="postfix">м<sup>2</sup></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="main-price">
                            3 500 000<span class="postfix">₽</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="metr-price">
                            45 000<span class="postfix">₽ / м<sup>2</sup></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'Домов по вашему запросу не найдено =(';
    endif;
 
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACF сохраняет свои значения в таблицу #__postmeta с ключом, соответствующим имени поля.

Соответственно Вам в коде функции new_filter_function() нужно заменить :

```
'key' => _price,
```

на

```
'key' => 'cost-house',
```

Comment: спасибо, я пробовал так до вашего ответа, и не работало, но я понял причину, если не выбрать категорию,а например применить фильтр только по цене, то он не работает. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы фильтр работал и без указания категории